# xna model turning on its side, camera related

Tags: c#, xna, camera

I have 3 classes: a game class, a camera class and a model class. The project builds and runs, 
the model appears, when i press w and make it go forward the camera follows it, but when i restart the project and rotate the model to face any other ways it seems to do a nose dive, and not go stright, what im trying to achieve is a camera which follows the model,

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;

namespace test1
{
/// <summary>
/// This is the main type for your game
/// </summary>
public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;



    //Visual components
    Ship ship = new Ship();
    Camera _camera;

    public Game1()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";



    }

   protected override void Initialize()
    {
     //   this.graphics.ToggleFullScreen(); 
        this._camera = new Camera(graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport);
        this._camera.LookAt = new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

        this._camera.Position = new Vector3(0.0f, -5000.0f, 1000.0f);


        base.Initialize();
    }


    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        ship.Model = Content.Load<Model>("Models/p1_wedge");
        ship.Transforms = _camera.SetupEffectDefaults(ship.Model);


    }


    protected override void UnloadContent()
    {
        // TODO: Unload any non ContentManager content here
    }


    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {

        // Allows the game to exit
        if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed ||
            Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape))
            this.Exit();

        // Get some input.
        UpdateInput();




        base.Update(gameTime);
    }

    protected void UpdateInput()
    {
        // Get the game pad state.
        GamePadState currentState = GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One);
        KeyboardState currentKeyState = Keyboard.GetState();

            ship.Update(currentState);



        }


    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        graphics.GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

        //camera
        this._camera.Update();
        _camera.LookAt = ship.Position;

        Matrix shipTransformMatrix = ship.RotationMatrix
                * Matrix.CreateTranslation(ship.Position);
        DrawModel(ship.Model, shipTransformMatrix, ship.Transforms);



        base.Draw(gameTime);

    }


    public void DrawModel(Model model, Matrix modelTransform, 
Matrix[] absoluteBoneTransforms)
{
//Draw the model, a model can have multiple meshes, so loop
foreach (ModelMesh mesh in model.Meshes)
{
    //This is where the mesh orientation is set
    foreach (BasicEffect effect in mesh.Effects)
    {
        effect.World = 
            absoluteBoneTransforms[mesh.ParentBone.Index] * 
            modelTransform;
        effect.Projection = _camera.ProjectionMatrix;
        effect.View = _camera.ViewMatrix; 
    }


    //Draw the mesh, will use the effects set above.
    mesh.Draw();
}
}


        }
    }
```

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;

namespace test1
{
public class Camera
{

    private Vector3 _position;
    private Vector3 _lookAt;
    private Matrix _viewMatrix;
    private Matrix _projectionMatrix;
    private float _aspectRatio;


 public Camera(Viewport viewport)
{
    this._aspectRatio = ((float)viewport.Width) / ((float)viewport.Height);

    this._projectionMatrix = Matrix.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(
                                MathHelper.ToRadians(40.0f),
                                this._aspectRatio,
                                1.0f,
                                10000.0f);
}


 public Matrix[] SetupEffectDefaults(Model myModel)
{
 Matrix[] absoluteTransforms = new Matrix[myModel.Bones.Count];
 myModel.CopyAbsoluteBoneTransformsTo(absoluteTransforms);

 foreach (ModelMesh mesh in myModel.Meshes)
 {
     foreach (BasicEffect effect in mesh.Effects)
     {
         effect.EnableDefaultLighting();
         effect.Projection = ProjectionMatrix;
         effect.View = ViewMatrix;
     }
 }
 return absoluteTransforms;
 }



public Vector3 Position
{
    get { return this._position; }
    set { this._position = value; }
}
public Vector3 LookAt //= Vector3.Zero;

{
    get { return this._lookAt; }
    set { this._lookAt = value; }
}

public Matrix ViewMatrix
{
    get { return this._viewMatrix; }
}
public Matrix ProjectionMatrix
{
    get { return this._projectionMatrix; }
}
public void Update()
{
    this._viewMatrix = 
        Matrix.CreateLookAt(this._position, this._lookAt, Vector3.Up);

}


}
}
```

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;


namespace test1
{
class Ship
{
    public Model Model;
    public Matrix[] Transforms;

    //Position of the model in world space
    public Vector3 Position = Vector3.Zero;

    //Velocity of the model, applied each frame to the model's position
    public Vector3 Velocity = Vector3.Zero;
    private const float VelocityScale = 5.0f;

    public Matrix RotationMatrix =
 Matrix.CreateRotationX(MathHelper.PiOver2);

    private float rotation;

    public float Rotation
    {
        get { return rotation; }
        set
        {
            float newVal = value;
            while (newVal >= MathHelper.TwoPi)
            {
                newVal -= MathHelper.TwoPi;
            }
            while (newVal < 0)
            {
                newVal += MathHelper.TwoPi;
            }

            if (rotation != value)
            {
                rotation = value;
                RotationMatrix =
                    Matrix.CreateRotationX(MathHelper.PiOver2) *
                    Matrix.CreateRotationZ(rotation);
            }

        }
    }

    public void Update(GamePadState controllerState)
    {

        KeyboardState currentKeyState = Keyboard.GetState();
        if (currentKeyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.A))
            Rotation += 0.10f;
        else
        // Rotate the model using the left thumbstick, and scale it down.
        Rotation -= controllerState.ThumbSticks.Left.X * 0.10f;

        if (currentKeyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.D))
            Rotation -= 0.10f;

        if (currentKeyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.W))
            Velocity += RotationMatrix.Forward * VelocityScale;
        else
        // Finally, add this vector to our velocity.
        Velocity += RotationMatrix.Forward * VelocityScale *
         controllerState.Triggers.Right;

        // In case you get lost, press A to warp back to the center.
        if  (currentKeyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Enter))
        {
            Position = Vector3.Zero;
            Velocity = Vector3.Zero;
            Rotation = 0.0f;

        }

        Position += Velocity;
        Velocity *= 0.95f;
    }



}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it this way:

[image: Schema]

I'm showing it in a plane to easy understanding, but it's not needed to do the calcs.

You only need a forward vector for the camera, a forward vector for the ship, a distance from the camera to the ship and an elevation vector for the camera.

this way when ship moves would do something similar to this:

```
 Camera.Forward = Vector3.Lerp( Ship.Forward, Camera.Fordward, 0.05f);
 Camera.Forward.Normalize();
 Camera.Forward*=Camera.Distance;
 Camera.Target = Ship.Target;
 Camera.Source = Ship.Target - Camera.Forward;
 Camera.Position = Camera.Source + Camera.Elevation;
```

I hope this will be useful.

Comment: Camera.Source,what would that be?

Comment: then this would be 0, 0, 0, ?

Comment: if you want that the camera to follow the ship it can't be static it will be Camera.Source = Ship.Target - Camera.Forward

Comment: so lets say i create a vector source, how does the camera know what it does let how its ment to the source point?

Comment: The source point is calculated as described above, and it's only used to calculate the camera position... I have referenced it to describe the operations related to the draw... but you can calculate the camera position as Ship.Target - Camera.Forward + Camera.Elevation

Comment: `_camera.Forward = Vector3.Lerp(ship.Velocity,  _camera.Forward, 0.05f);`
            `_camera.Forward.Normalize();`
            `_camera.Forward *= _camera.Position;`
            `_camera.LookAt = ship.Position;`
            `_camera.Position = ship.Position;`
            `_camera.Source = ship.Position - _camera.Forward;`
            `_camera.Position = _camera.Source + _camera.Elevation;` lets say i have this, in my Draw method in my main class, im getting  errors saysing my _camera calss deosnt contain Source or elevation, what would i use from my _camera calss to replace them?

Comment: _camera.Forward *= _camera.Position has no sense, you have to multiply  Camera.Forward by the distance you want the camera follow your ship....(you want the forward vector length to be equal to that distance), ...  _Camera.Position = ship.Position has no sense too... ¿do you want the camera to be in the ship? Try to understand the drawing, and should appreciate the differences among vectors, points, and scalars.